# I would like to know how to reindex Express program (.CDX) files using PHP

Tags: php, visual-foxpro, dbf, reindex, xbase

Currently, I can insert data using the xbase library in PHP, but I'm facing an issue where I have to manually reindex the data in the Express program after inserting it. I would like to know how to write a PHP program that can trigger a reindexing process after inserting data.
Here is the code I'm using for the insert

```
$remote_path8 = 'GLJNLIT.DBF';
  $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'dbf_temp');
  $connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
  ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass);
  if (ftp_get($connection, $temp_file, $remote_path8, FTP_BINARY)){

  $table1 = new TableEditor(
    $temp_file,
    [
        'editMode' => TableEditor::EDIT_MODE_CLONE,
    ]
  );
     $record1 = $table1->appendRecord();
     $record->set('VOUCHER', '111111');
     $record1->set('Seqit', '3');
     $record1->set('Voudat', '20231107');
     $record1->set('Accnum', '1154-00');
     $record1->set('Depcod', '');
     $record1->set('Jobcod', '');
     $record1->set('Phase', '');
     $record1->set('Coscod', '');
     $record1->set('Descrp', 'JIB');
     $record1->set('Trntyp', '0');
     $record1->set('Amount', '1');
     $record1->set('Chgdat', '20231107');
     $record1->set('Chgtim', '0951');
     $record1->set('Adjust', '');
     $record1->set('Chgaccfrom', '');

     $table1
     ->writeRecord($record1)
     ->save()
     ->close();

      ftp_put($connection, $remote_path8, $temp_file, FTP_BINARY); 
      ftp_close($connection);
      unlink($temp_file);

    echo "<br> DBF file GLJNL<br>";
  }else{
    echo "<br>Error downloading DBF file GLJNL";
  }
```

Comment: unable to see the code which re-index the data

Answer (score 1):

The [php-xbase](https://github.com/luads/php-xbase) library has no support for indexes, as you can see [here](https://github.com/luads/php-xbase/issues/16):

> I don't know how the CDX files work, so I don't plan to implement it soon.